# AES decrytion issue in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aes, caesar-cipher

I want to decrypt 'RLs4yZ1Ku0Ylf4CfVShU1g=='

Error shown

> unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])],   TypeError: ord() expected a
> character, but string of length 0 found

Here is my code for decryption

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode
from base64 import b64decode

BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]

class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = b'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        self.iv = b'123edfr4@#90&65$'
        
    def encrypt(self, data):
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
        _pad = pad(data).encode('utf-8')
        response = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(_pad)).decode('utf-8')
        print(response)

    def decrypt( self, data):
        enc = base64.b64decode(data)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv )
        self._unpad = unpad
        response = self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf-8')
        print(response)

def test():    
    response = AESCipher().decrypt('RLs4yZ1Ku0Ylf4CfVShU1g==')
    return response
    
output = test()
```

Python version = 3.6.10

Comment: What is `AES`?  That is not a standard Python module.

Comment: its Crypto Cipher AES

Comment: Is there any issues on that?

Comment: To decrypt `RLs...`, replace `enc[AES.block_size:]` with `enc` in `decrypt()`, because IV and ciphertext are obviously not concatenated during encryption. However, since a static IV is insecure, the better solution would be to concatenate IV and ciphertext during encryption (along with a random IV)!

Comment: Also, PyCryptodome supports PKCS#7 padding ([Crypto.Util.Padding](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-package)), so there is no need for a custom implementation (besides, your padding operates directly on strings, which is wrong, s. your last question).

Comment: okay, its working fine now